# Linux Distribute Big File and Gather Results

Tags: java, python, shell, distribute

(Don't suggest Hadoop or map reduce solution even they sounds logically the same)

I have a big file - 70GB of raw html files and I need to do the parsing to get the information I need.

I have delt with 10GB file successfully before using standardI/O:

```
cat input_file | python parse.py > output_file
```

And in my python script, it reads every html (each html per line) from standard input and writes the result back to standard output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print ....
```

The code is very simple but right now, I am dealing with a big file which is horribly slow on one node. I have a cluster of about 20 nodes. And I am wondering how could I easily distribute this work.

What I have done so far:

```
split -l 5000 input_file.all input_file_   # I have 60K lines in total in that 70G file
```

Now the big file have been splitted into several small files:

```
input_file_aa
input_file_ab
input_file_ac
...
```

Then I have no problem working with each one of them:

```
cat input_file_aa | python parser.py > output_file_aa
```

What I gonna do is probably scp the input_file to each node and do the parsing and then scp the result back, but there are 10+ nodes! I it is so tedious to do that manually.

I am wondering how could I easily distribute these files to other nodes and do the parsing and move the result back?

I am open to basic SHELL, JAVA, Python solution. Thanks a lot in advance and let me know if you need more explanation.

Note, I do have a folder called /bigShare/ that could be assessible on every node and the contents are synchronized and stay the same.  I don't know how the architect implemented that (NFS..? I don't know how to check) but I could put my input_file and python script there so the rest is how to easily log into those nodes and execute the command. 
Btw, I am on Red Hat.

Comment: Why are you trying to build your own distributed computing system? What's wrong with the options you don't want us to suggest? Without knowing why those don't fit, we're going to be missing important information.

Comment: Put it on a NFS drive?

Comment: @user2357112 The cluster is an enterprise cluster and I don't have the root to install a new structure on it. For <jman>, I am not quite sure what is NFS but we do have a folder /share that existing on every node and have the same content synchronized. Now I see I could easily distribute the input_file but how could I easily let all these nodes run the command?

Comment: Note: You don't need to `cat` the input to your program. You can just redirect stdin: `python parser.py < input_file_aa > output_file_aa`. Saves a bit of overhead.

Comment: @user2357112 Is there any difference between cat xx | python .. and python .. < xx? Any memory improvement..?

Comment: @B.Mr.W.  Absolutely.  Not only the memory that `cat` uses, but also a bit of CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the command remotely with remote piping to stdout.  Then make the local command pipe to a local file.

Example:

```
ssh yourUserName@node1 "cat input_file_node1 | python parser.py" >output_file_node1
```

If the files have not been copied to the different nodes, then:

```
ssh yourUserName@node1 "python parser.py" <input_file_node1 >output_file_node1
```

This assumes that yourUserName has been configured with key-based authentication.  Otherwise, you will need to enter your password manually (20 times! :-( ).  To avoid this, you can use `expect`, but I will strongly suggest to setup key-based authentication.  You can do the later using `expect` too.

Comment: I don't know if the colors look the same for us but.. the red command(double quoted) are actually the command that gonna run on the other nodes. The black commands/files are actually the ones on local machines.. Right?

Comment: @B.Mr.W.  That was a bit of a coincidence, but yes:  the black part happens locally, and the red part remotely.

Comment: your answer is very inspiring and I have a last question. I have no problem running each command but after the command, the terminal hangs there. You are suggesting me use 20 nohup?

Comment: @B.Mr.W.  That's correct.  But first be sure that the program is running in the remote machine and not waiting for input (password?) or something like that.  You can try running "`expr 1 + 1`" remotely without redirection (2 should come back).  You could also try a shorter version of your file (something that comes back quickly).  Just to be sure things are working.  You should probably test all nodes in this way before the big run (unless you are positive they are configured the same).

Comment: thank you so much. I have successfully split the work into 13 files and used 13 nodes to finish that already while the 'comparison object' is still crunching its way through 30%! However, one of the node failed due to some unexpected reason but I might just assign that to some other node to taking care of. Thanks alot!

Comment: @B.Mr.W.  Very glad to hear that and have had the chance of contributing, as other SO members, my 2 cents.

Comment: Another question is my concern about the memory, so you do 20 ssh on the starting node, say node_01, read input file from standard input and output file to standard output. All those 20 stdI/O would mess up the memory? Or could you point me to some resources that I could have a better understanding of stdI/O or Shell... thanks –

Comment: @B.Mr.W.  Extremely little.  Files are not loaded into memory, but passed directly from disk to the other node through the network.  There is some buffering, of course, but not comparable to file size.  10, 20 MB total (0.5~1 MB each)?  It's probably much less.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to process a piece of each file on a host of its own: first copy the python script to the remote hosts. Then loop over the remote hosts:

```
for x in aa ab ac ...; do
   ssh user@remote-$x python yourscript.py <input_file_$x >output_file_$x &
done;
```

If the processing nodes don't have names that are easy to generate you can create aliases for them in your `.ssh/config`, for example:

```
Host remote-aa
    Hostname alpha.int.youcompany

Host remote-ab
    Hostname beta.int.yourcompany

Host remote-ac
    Hostname gamma.int.yourcompany
```

This particular use case could be more easily solved by editing /etc/hosts though.

Comment: I went to ~/.ssh/ and there is no file called config, but there is a file called known_hosts which contains the name, ip, ssh-rsa .... I don't know if this is the file you mentioned.

Comment: The `config` file does not exist until you create it.

Comment: Another question is my concern about the memory, so you do 20 ssh on the starting node, say node_01, read input file from standard input and output file to standard output. All those 20 stdI/O would mess up the memory? Or could you point me to some resources that I could have a better understanding of stdI/O or Shell... thanks

Comment: The starting node only pipes data from disk to a network connection, and from a network connection to disk, without accumulating it in memory. Memory usage will be minimal.